# Не могу найти пользователя

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, комментарии, уведомления

Привет. Пытаюсь обратиться к пользователю через @, но ник не высвечивается. При попытке записать ник пользователя руками, в комментарий он не добавляется:

[image: Скрин 1]

[image: Скрин 2]

Comment: к тс нужно обращаться без указания, нотификация так и так придет. а вот обращение к участникам писавшим комментарии под вопросом/ответам лучше писать через символ `@`+НикПользователя

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Автору вопроса/ответа под которым оставляются комментарии - **всегда** приходят оповещения. Поэтому указывать его ник в общем случае - не обязательно.

В данном случае, дополнительно работает правило, по которому, если в комментариях на данный момент участвуют ***всего два*** участника, то комментарии рассматриваются как диалог, и оповещения приходят обоим участникам, даже без использования `@`.

Это продолжается до тех пор, пока не появится комментарий третьего участника. После этого, для указания участника, кому отправлен ответ используется `@nickName`. Как сказано выше, автору вопроса/ответа, оповещения приходят всегда, поэтому упоминание его как `@nickName` может быть использовано для того, чтобы сделать комментарий более личным.

Comment: забыл про режим диалога, так что свой ответ удалю — у вас полнее.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, где ты берешь такие длинные тире??? :-D ну и я как-то долго формулировал :)

Comment: На маке тире сразу есть в раскладке. (А короткие — это не тире, а дефисы/минусы.) А вообще, рекомендую http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/.

Comment: Тире (длинное) — Alt + 0151 ,  Короткое (среднее) тире – Alt + 0150  ....... Вообще Alt + цифры дают много вариантов https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4  ;-)