# Не всегда работает упоминание участника в комментах

Tags: дефект

Я пишу:

`@ИмяУчастника текст комментария`

И иногда автодополнение не показывается при наборе имени. В 100% таких случаев упоминание пропадает при отправке коммента. Не могу точно вспомнить связь с тем, чтобы имя содержало кириллицу, но последний случай был с русским ником. Отображается:

`текст комментария`

Если нажать **Править**, упоминания также там не будет. Бесследно стирается.

Браузер - Firefox 47.0 (Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0)

Был вопрос [Кого можно позвать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2576/319552). Тот вопрос был о том, кого можно упомянуть в вопросе, а кого нельзя, но мой вопрос о том, что я упоминаю того, кого **точно** можно позвать, а именно участника, уже оставившего комментарий, и я хочу ответить на его комментарий.

Что это, баг сайта или я что-то неправильно делаю?

Comment: Если в переписке никого кроме автора вопроса не было, то упоминание автора вопроса бессмысленно и автоматически вырезается. Если попытаться упомянуть участника, которого не было в переписке, то [система не даст зафлудить его уведомлениями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9235). Короче, не баг, а фича

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2576/178988

Comment: @andreymal то есть если я отвечаю на коммент участника, который сам и задал вопрос, то система сотрет уведомление, а он все равно получит ответ? Это может быть разгадкой. Но почему тогда система не стирает *его* обращение ко мне?

Comment: Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5022/319552